# Order by field in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, sql-order-by

I am doing project in cakephp .

I want to write below query in cakephp Style. I've written 50% . Please help me

$this->Login->find('all')

```
SELECT * FROM login  
ORDER BY FIELD(profile_type, 'Basic', 'Premium') DESC;
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Plese try this

```
$this->Login->find('all', array(
 'order'=>array('FIELD(Login.profile_type, "basic", "premium") DESC')
));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass options to [the `find` method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html):

```
$this->Login->find('all', array(
  'order' => "FIELD(Login.profile_type, 'Basic', 'Premium') DESC"
));
```

Answer (score 4):

This one is more easy way to order and limit that works fine

```
$this->set('users', 
    $this->User->find('all', 
        array(
            'limit' => 3,
            'order' => 'User.created DESC'
       )
   )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please, try this:

```
$response = $this->Login->find('all', array('order'=>array('Login.profile_type'=>'desc')));
```