# CakePHP admin panel order

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to order the table by 'Sr. No' in descending order. I'm not sure how because it's not from a database, but php generated.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Sr. No</th>
        <th>Naslov</th>
    </tr>
    <?php $counter = 0; foreach($posts as $post) : $counter++; ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $counter?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'], array('controller' => 'Posts', 'action'=> 'view', $post['Post']['id']), array('class' => 'link')); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php unset($post); ?>
</table>
```

Comment: can you show us where $posts is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `$counter`in decreasing order like below:-

```
<?php $counter = count($posts); foreach($posts as $post) : $counter--; ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $counter?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'], array('controller' => 'Posts', 'action'=> 'view', $post['Post']['id']), array('class' => 'link')); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If you want `Naslov` (means Posts) also in decreasing order then in query you have to do `ORDER BY <column name like id> DESC`

Check How to apply `DESC`:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9837302/4248328

An example:- `$this->Post->find('all', array('order' =>array('Post.id DESC')));`